# How do I implement a cache buster , if I use git?

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates, url

```
<link rel="/style/style.css"/>
```

So this is my index.html.

If I save it, I want to automatically implement style.css?version=3 ...so this busts the cache

What's the easiest way to do that?

Comment: Where does javascript fit in?

Answer (score -7, accepted):

using javascript you can just write

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?version=' + (new Date()).getTime() + '">');
</script>
```

Can easier be done if you use any server-side scripting. Something like `

```
<link href="/style/style.css?version=<?php echo time() ?>">`
```

Comment: This will force an update every request. Ideally a cache buster should take effect only if the file has changed, that's why the user is asking for using the git revision tag (which is what I came looking for). Still, if you do want a reload every request, don't use random, it never makes sense to do that. The better option is to use time because it will always be different. Random can produce duplicates, even if it is unlikely, it's much simpler to still use time. In javascript this is `(new Date()).getTime()` and simply `time()` in PHP.

Answer (score 4):

If you use git, you can use `git describe --tags --always` to get the current version.

If in PHP, you can do something like :

```
$currentVersion = `git describe --tags --always`
```

An then us $currentVersion as a cache buster :

```
<link href="/style/style.css?version=<?=$currentVersion?>">
```

Of course :

- you *should* cache the result of the command, at least for one minute, to prevent intensive calls to the git command !
- be sure that the command is launched in a GIT directory

It will work even in you don't use tags (thanks to the `--always` switch), but it's nicer to use them, so $currentVersion would be something like `v2.1.3-c1a2f3e`.